# "Ich kümmere mich darum, dass...", "Ich rede darüber, dass..." – are 'darum' und 'darüber' redundant?

Tags: preposition, sentence-structure

Whenever I am using verbs that are complemented by prepositions like i.e. "*sich **um** etw. kümmern*" or "***über** etw reden*" and I am about to introduce a subordinate clause, I never know if I should include those prepositions in the main clause as in:

> Ich kümmere mich **darum**, dass sie nie hungrig sind.

or

> Ich möchte **darüber** reden, was geschehen ist.

Are **darum** and **darüber** redundant? Would it be enough to say:

> Ich kümmere mich, dass sie nie hungrig sind
>
> Ich möchte reden, was geschehen ist.

I chose these two verbs purposefully as my gut feeling tells me that the first sentence does not require **darum**, whereas the second one sounds unnatural without **darüber**. Still, I have no idea why. Which is correct? Is there a rule that covers this subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your example sentences require to retain the preposition. If it's not required one time or another, you faced a free adverbial instead of a prepositional object.

> Ich kümmere mich **um acht Uhr** darum.

See how the *darum* is still required?

Those *hier-* and *da-* variants of the prepositions are used for backreferences. You may see them as shortcuts for demonstrative expressions:

> Ich kümmere mich um acht Uhr **um dies hier.**
>
> Ich kümmere mich um acht Uhr **um jenes da.**

---

English has a slightly different way to express the same thing but retains the preposition as German does:

> Ich kümmere mich **darum**, dass sie nie hungrig sind.

*I care **about** them never being hungry.*

> Ich möchte **darüber** reden, was geschehen ist.

*I want to talk **about** what happened.*